# How reassigning pointers affects polymorphism

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

Here is something I'm wondering about. There are 2 pointers corresponding to 2 class instances. The code prints out 6 lines (as per the comments). The first 4 make sense to me, but I don't understand the last 2. I would have expected lines 5 and 6 to equal lines 3 and 4 since `pb` an `pd` are now both pointing to the same object. Please help me understand.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:
  virtual void run1(){cout << "Base" << endl;}
  void run2(){cout << "Base" << endl;}
};

class D: public B {
public:
  virtual void run1(){cout << "Derived" << endl;}
  void run2(){cout << "Derived" << endl;}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  B b, *pb;
  D d, *pd;

  pb = &b;
  pb->run1(); //Base
  pb->run2(); //Base

  pd = &d;
  pd->run1(); //Derived
  pd->run2(); //Derived

  pb = &d;
  pb->run1(); //Derived (why ?)
  pb->run2(); //Base    (why ?)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `run1` is a virtual function while the function `run2` is not a virtual function.

Virtual functions are called according to the dynamic type of a used pointer while non-virtual functions are called according to the static type of a used pointer.

The static type of the pointer `pb` is `B *`.

```
  B b, *pb;
```

After this assignment

```
pb = &b;
```

the dynamic type of the pointer is also `B *`. So the virtual function defined in the class `B` is called.

After this assignment

```
pb = &d;
```

the dynamic type of the pointer `pb` changed from `B *` to  `D *`.

So in this statement

```
pb->run1(); //Derived (why ?)
```

there is called a virtual function according to the dynamic type of the pointer. While in this statement

```
pb->run2(); //Base    (why ?)
```

there is called a non-virtual function according to the static type of the pointer.

That is the pointer to the table of virtual function pointers is searched in the object pointed to by the used pointer.

This feature defines a polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense. So, I guess it's also accurate to say that it boils down to compile-time (static) vs runtime (dynamic) linking of the pointers to objects?

Comment: The dynamic type (there is technically no such thing, but I see what you mean) of a pointer is its static type (or just type), just as with any other scalar type.

Comment: @curiousguy From the C++ Standard  "if a pointer (8.3.1) p whose static type is “pointer to class B” is pointing to an object of class
D, derived from B (Clause 10), the dynamic type of the expression *p is “D.” References (8.3.2) are treated
similarly. —"